# How to Debug GAE using Komodo IDE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, komodo

A few years ago I could debug GAE using Komodo IDE when using GAE by:

1. From within Komodo IDE, select "Debug | Go"
2. For [Script] enter C:\Progra~2\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py
3. For [Directory] enter C:\Users\Me\MyProject
4. For [Script Arguments] enter App (name of MyProject subdir holding project)
5. Check "Debug in separate console"
6. Click OK

But, with a new dev setup (Win 8.1, Komodo 8.5.3, App Engine 1.9.2) the separate command window comes up, but just hangs with no output. When I open a command prompt manually, go to the Directory named above, and type the Script command with the App argument, things run. If I do this via the Run Command in Komodo, it also works.

But I can't get it to work in Debug mode. I hope it's just something simple; I'm a little rusty after several years doing other things.

In fact, here's an old link to an [ActiveState blog](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2009/01/debugging-google-app-engine-sdk) that appears to say what I said above. But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folks over at Komodo helped me [resolve this](http://forum.komodoide.com/t/google-app-engine-debugging-hangs-doesnt-start/132/15).

Basically,

- Ensure Edit | Preferences | Debugger | Connection has port set to 9000
- Add a new command in Toolbox

  - **Command**: C:\Python27\python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" --python_startup_script C:\Komodo_Debug.py C:\MyFiles\App
  - **Start In**: C:\MyFiles
  - **Run In**: New Console

where Komodo_Debug.py contains

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\lib\support\dbgp\pythonlib")  # path to Komodo dbgp library
from dbgp import client
client.brk()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [old devserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver#Running_the_Old_Development_Web_Server) with the old instructions:

> Once you have a directory for your application and an app.yaml configuration file, you can start the development web server with the old_dev_appserver.py command:
>
> old_dev_appserver.py myapp

**References**

- [The Python Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver)
- [How do I run code interactively from in the editor?](http://community.activestate.com/node/9398)